# Can you download Android Studio on Mac High Sierra

Tags: android, android-studio, macos-high-sierra

I'm new to developing and a mentor advised I download Android Studio.

I have a late 2011 Macbook Pro so it can't get a more updated OS than 10.13.6 High Sierra.

I see in the Android Studio system requirements that you need MacOS 10.14 (Mojave).

https://developer.android.com/studio#Requirements

I was just curious if anyone knew of a work around to this so that I could install Android Studio on my comp.

My system meets all the other requirements.

Thanks,
Kyle

Comment: I don't think a lot of people put effort into those kind of work arounds, when rather than spending tens of hours doing that they can just get a new ultra low end machine that will work fine.  I mean your machine is 10 years old-  you can get PCs 5 years newer out of a literal junkyard.

Answer (score 2):

Try an older version. This one requires Yosemite, so it works in High Sierra:
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/install/4.0.1.0/android-studio-ide-193.6626763-mac.dmg

Another workaround is to use DosDude1's Mojave Patcher tool to upgrade your old mac to Mojave: http://dosdude1.com/mojave/